# How to include QList in QTabWidget with QWidget

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtabwidget

First of all, I code with the help of the Qt Creator.

For a private project I want to build a Tab box with 3 pages, while each page should represent a table/listing of different attributes of objects.
The objects are in a QList (Container), 1 for each page.

I just want to show/display, not to change the information.

I already created a QTabWidget object and a QWidget object for each page.

- How can I represent the information? is there a specific class of QT I could use?
- How do I access the single attributes of an object?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The QList is a class for creating and managing list-based data. To render that in a model (your QTabWidget) you need to map the model using QListView.

[QListView details](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#details)